# htaccess ignore a third party library in a Codeigniter application

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I want to access an index.php file contained within the third_party folder in my Codeigniter application via direct url like www.website.com/app/external/www

My application structure is like this:

```
application/
   library/
   third_party/
      external/
         www/
```

I have tried

```
RewriteRule ^app/external/www /app/application/third_party/external/www/$1 [L]
```

but it doesn't work.

Here is the full htaccess file in case anything else is affecting it.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?website.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?website.com.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(pdf)$ - [F]
```

Hope someone can see what I'm missing

UPDATE:

This is the htaccess file on the same level as the application directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    #THIS LINE ALLOWS BASIC AUTH FOR REST DO NOT DELETE#
    RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) app/$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/php-fpm/*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(third_party) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/index.php/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule \.(pdf)$ - [F]

</IfModule>
```

Update 2: This is the htaccess file that controls the visibility of the directories. How do i exclude the third_party folder from the url rewrite? So far this method doesn't work

Comment: codeigniter usually comes with separate htaccess files that are present in the sub directories. make sure another htaccess isn't effecting this.

Comment: I have added some htaccess files and their location

Comment: try deleting that htaccess and see if it starts working

Comment: I have added some comments.